# Unity creates big size .apk file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I'm new to game dev and Unity.
I checked a lot of sites for an answer, so things like "select the ARMv7 only in Device Filter" and "use mscorlib" won't work, because I already used them.

### Some data from Editor Log:

```
Textures      1.6 mb     26.2% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    13.4 kb    0.2% 
Sounds        153.8 kb   2.4% 
Shaders       0.0 kb     0.0% 
Other Assets  12.6 kb    0.2% 
Levels        11.5 kb    0.2% 
Scripts       465.8 kb   7.3% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     63.2% 
File headers  13.1 kb    0.2% 
Complete size 6.2 mb     100.0%
```

Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:

```
1.6 mb   25.2% Assets/Zero/Sprite/Game.psd
 69.7 kb     1.1% Assets/Zero/Sound/Start.wav
 36.7 kb     0.6% Assets/Zero/Sound/Success.mp3
 34.2 kb     0.5% Assets/Zero/Sprite/UI/MediaIcon_1.png
 33.4 kb     0.5% Assets/Zero/Sprite/UI/MediaIcon_2.png
 32.7 kb     0.5% Assets/Zero/Sound/correct.wav
 13.9 kb     0.2% Assets/Zero/Sound/soundfalse.wav
 5.7 kb  0.1% Resources/unity_builtin_extra
 4.0 kb  0.1% C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/UnityEngine.UI.dll
 3.6 kb  0.1% Assets/Zero/Animation/Picker.controller
 2.6 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Count2Zero.controller
 2.3 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Picker Fail.anim
 2.3 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Picker Show.anim
 2.3 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Picker Hide.anim
 2.2 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Picker.anim
 2.2 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/MenuShow.controller
 2.2 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/Count2Zero.anim
 2.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Animation/MenuShow.anim
 1.8 kb  0.0% C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Networking/UnityEngine.Networking.dll
 0.7 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Sound/Click.wav
 0.1 kb  0.0% C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/Advertisements/UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/AdmobListenerProxy.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/UnityAnalytics/UnityEngine.Analytics.dll
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/IAdmobListener.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/AdmobEvent.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/AdPosition.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/Admob.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Plugins/AdmobAPI/AdSize.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/SoundManager.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/GlobalValue.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/GameManager.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/AdManager.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/PickerID.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/Picker.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/MainMenu.cs
 0.1 kb  0.0% Assets/Zero/Script/Spin.cs
```

---

So how come the .apk file can have 11.8 MB?!?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 11 MB is nothing, forget about it

Comment: You're only looking at the size of your assets.  The engine itself (AndroidPlayer) takes some space, then there is encryption and Android generated files etc...  11MB is tiny.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!